# dificuldade sqrt()

Tags: c

preciso calcular a área de um triângulo retângulo porém não consigo identificar o erro.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main() 
{
 //declaracao de variaveis
 int a, b, c;
 int s;
 int s1, s2, s3;
 int total;
 int area;
 int sa, sb, sc;
 //inicio
 printf("digite 'a': ");
 scanf("%d", &a);

 printf("digite 'b': ");
 scanf("%d", &b);

 printf("digite 'c': ");
 scanf("%d", &c);

 s = (a + b + c) / (2);

 area = (s * (s - a) * s *(s - b) * s * (s - c);
 printf("\nAREA: %.2d", area);

 return(0);
```

Comment: Na variável ```area```, você abriu um parênteses e não fechou, antes do ```printf``` do resultado.

Comment: A variável `s`, bem como `area`, não deveria ser `float`?

Comment: Erro meu, a varíavel deveria ser float mesmo!

Comment: Mas seria necessário adicionar o comando sqrt() na varíavel 'area' e não sei como fazer ;(

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o sqrt diretamente no printf

```
printf("\nAREA: %.2d", sqrt(area));
```

Answer (score 0):

A área de um triângulo retângulo pode ser calculado usando a seguinte fórmula: área = (base * altura) / 2.

Para ter um precisão melhor recomendo usar o tipo double.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Qual é a base: ");
  double base = 0.0;
  scanf("%lf", &base);

  printf("Qual é a altura: ");
  double altura = 0.0;
  scanf("%lf", &altura);

  double area = (base * altura) / 2;

  printf("Área: %lf\n", area);

  return 0;
}
```